# Javascript object/array as key for Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's the best way to use 2 string variables as the key for a `Map`?

```
const map = new Map();
map.set(['a', 'b'], 5);
map.get(['a', 'b']); //undefined
```

Creating a reference to `[v1, v2]` and using that as key is not an option for my case.

Is the only option to combine the two variables with a delimiter? (will be messy if the string variables can potentially contain the delimiter character).

Comment: I think you want to create two maps a -> b -> 5 (in your example). Am I right?

Comment: @Ori Dor and, Jonasw, the sequence may matter, as the array will be again constructed, and the OP wants to make the combination as a key, so better to sort before stringify

Comment: @Jonasw yes, might be, the sequence also can be a part of the key, so completely depend on use case. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May nest the Map:

```
var map=new Map();

function set(key1,key2,value){
  if(map.has(key1)){
    return map.get(key1).set(key2,value);
  }
  return map.set(key1,new Map([[key2,value]]));
}

function get(key1,key2){
 if(map.has(key1)){
  return map.get(key1).get(key2);
 }
 return false;
}

set("a","b","value");
console.log(get("a","b"))
```

If you want a variable length of keys, you may recursively create Maps and add an *exit delimiter* at the end, probably a symbol:

```
var exit=Symbol("exit");
set("a",exit,"value");
set("a","b",exit,"value");
```

Comment: Pretty neat solution